# Error when trying to run command "npm start"

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I was building a react project and during the final "npm start" stage, I got many errors:
please help me fix this.

C:\Users\Intel\Desktop\burger-project>npm start

> burger-project@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Intel\Desktop\burger-project 
> node scripts/start.js

Plugin could not be registered at 'html-webpack-plugin-before-html-processing'. Hook was not found.
BREAKING CHANGE: There need to exist a hook at 'this.hooks'. To create a compatibility layer for this hook, hook into 'this._pluginCompat'. 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE  
npm ERR! errno 1 
npm ERR! burger-project@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the burger-project@0.1.0 start script.  
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Intel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-09-22T17_01_17_645Z-debug.log

Also, this my `package.json` file of the project

```
 {
      "name": "burger-project",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "babel-core": "6.26.0",
        "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
        "babel-jest": "^26.3.0",
        "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
        "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
        "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
        "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
        "chalk": "1.1.3",
        "dotenv": "4.0.0",
        "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
        "eslint": "4.10.0",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
        "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
        "file-loader": "1.1.5",
        "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
        "jest": "^26.4.2",
        "npm-upgrade": "^2.0.4",
        "object-assign": "4.1.1",
        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
        "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
        "promise": "8.0.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "raf": "3.4.0",
        "react": "^16.8.0",
        "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "resolve": "1.6.0",
        "style-loader": "0.19.0",
        "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
        "url-loader": "0.6.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
        "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
        "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node scripts/start.js",
        "build": "node scripts/build.js",
        "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
      },
      "jest": {
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
          "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
        ],
        "setupFiles": [
          "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
        ],
        "testMatch": [
          "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
          "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
        ],
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "testURL": "http://localhost",
        "transform": {
          "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
          "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
          "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
          "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
        ],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
          "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
        },
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
          "web.js",
          "js",
          "json",
          "web.jsx",
          "jsx",
          "node",
          "mjs"
        ]
      },
      "babel": {
        "presets": [
          "react-app"
        ]
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.2",
        "css-loader": "^4.2.1",
        "html-webpack-beforehtml-plugin": "^1.0.0",
        "preload-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
        "webpack": "^4.44.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
      }
    }
```

this is code of start.js

```
//'use strict';

// Do this as the first thing so that any code reading it knows the right env.
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'development';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

// Makes the script crash on unhandled rejections instead of silently
// ignoring them. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
// terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  throw err;
});

// Ensure environment variables are read.
require('../config/env');

const fs = require('fs');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const clearConsole = require('react-dev-utils/clearConsole');
const checkRequiredFiles = require('react-dev-utils/checkRequiredFiles');
const {
  choosePort,
  createCompiler,
  prepareProxy,
  prepareUrls,
} = require('react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils');
const openBrowser = require('react-dev-utils/openBrowser');
const paths = require('../config/paths');
const config = require('../config/webpack.config.dev');
const createDevServerConfig = require('../config/webpackDevServer.config');

const useYarn = fs.existsSync(paths.yarnLockFile);
const isInteractive = process.stdout.isTTY;

// Warn and crash if required files are missing
if (!checkRequiredFiles([paths.appHtml, paths.appIndexJs])) {
  process.exit(1);
}

// Tools like Cloud9 rely on this.
const DEFAULT_PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const HOST = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';

// We attempt to use the default port but if it is busy, we offer the user to
// run on a different port. `detect()` Promise resolves to the next free port.
choosePort(HOST, DEFAULT_PORT)
  .then(port => {
    if (port == null) {
      // We have not found a port.
      return;
    }
    const protocol = process.env.HTTPS === 'true' ? 'https' : 'http';
    const appName = require(paths.appPackageJson).name;
    const urls = prepareUrls(protocol, HOST, port);
    // Create a webpack compiler that is configured with custom messages.
    const compiler = createCompiler(webpack, config, appName, urls, useYarn);
    // Load proxy config
    const proxySetting = require(paths.appPackageJson).proxy;
    const proxyConfig = prepareProxy(proxySetting, paths.appPublic);
    // Serve webpack assets generated by the compiler over a web sever.
    const serverConfig = createDevServerConfig(
      proxyConfig,
      urls.lanUrlForConfig
    );
    const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, serverConfig);
    // Launch WebpackDevServer.
    devServer.listen(port, HOST, err => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      if (isInteractive) {
        clearConsole();
      }
      console.log(chalk.cyan('Starting the development server...\n'));
      openBrowser(urls.localUrlForBrowser);
    });

    ['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'].forEach(function(sig) {
      process.on(sig, function() {
        devServer.close();
        process.exit();
      });
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (err && err.message) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: what is inside `scripts/start.js`? can you post it

Comment: @BesufkadMenji, I've added start.js code, kindly check! :)

Comment: if you created this project using `create-react-app` why dont you use react-scripts rather than using a custom script

Comment: @BesufkadMenji, I don't know about that, start.js was already there in create-react-app when I installed it for my project. Also, how do I fix this error?

Comment: @BesufkadMenji, but for modules and packages like "redux" and "axios" and all I'd have to install all of them again no, just copying dependencies won't work I guess? I'd installed lots of them during the project.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way in your case is to just create a new project using
`npx create-react-app your-project-name` and moving all your files from `src` to the new project `src` and also copying all of your dependencies from package.json to the new project package.json.

[for more on **Create React App**](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

Comment: Thanks. Also how do I copy all dependencies from package.json to the new project package.json ?

Comment: go to your package.json and find `"dependencies"` and `"devDependencies"`, copy everything inside these  objects to the new package.json

Comment: but for modules and packages like "redux" and all I'd have to install all of them again no, just copying them won't work I guess? I'd installed lots of them during the project.